# How to use Observable java

Tags: java

I have the following:

`abstract class A extends Class C (abstract class C extends D)`

```
private String name="";

public void setFff(double val) {

    double old = fff.getAvg();
    fff.update(val);

    ListIterator<Observer> it = fffListeners.listIterator();
    String ss;

    while (it.hasNext()) {
      ss = name + this.toString();
      it.next().update("fff", fff.getValue(), fff.getAvg(), ss);
    }
}
```

`class B extends D implements Observable`

```
private String name="";
public void notifyObservers() {
        for(Observer observer:fffListeners){
            v=fff.getValue();
             m=fff.getAvg();
            observer.update("fff", v, m, (name+this.getName()));
        }       
    }
```

`interface Observer`:

```
void update(String nn, double bbb, double aaa, String nameThraed);
```

`abstract class E implements Observer`

`class G extends E`

update in class G is the following

```
public void update(String string, double v, double m, String s) {

        if ((B.getClass == "G")
                && string.equals("fff")&& (s.equals("B"))) {

             this.fffList.add(m);
            System.out.println("List of fff :" + fffList);

        }
    myMethod(fffList);
}
```

I want to get all the value of `m` and put theme in the list `fffList` when I get a notification from `E`. How can i do that?

Comment: Your question as it stands is very difficult to understand. Could you take some efforts to explain in a better way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your post to remove code snippets. Please indented your code samples by 4 spaces so that they render properly. Code snippets are just for `HTML`, `Javascript` and `CSS`

Comment: I agree with @bot could you improve your code ?

Comment: my problem is how to deal with update(...)when it's called in multiple observable  for observer? i mean how does G know the sender?knowing that from nameThread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend your interface:

```
void update(Object sender, String nn, double bbb, double aaa, String nameThraed);
```

In your special case you can check if the sender is an instance of your class E.

```
if(sender instanceof E){
...
}
```

Hope this will help you. And please refactor your parameters:)

Comment: i need to use nameThraed to know the sender